# How to migrate android module to androidx?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

This android project has lots of modules, when I do Refactor->Migrate to androidx, source codes from module "app" upgraded,
[image: Only app module auto migrated]

but codes from modules are never migrated...

Now have to fix it buy lots of manual replacement.
Any idea how to migrate these modules? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added this code  **android.useAndroidX=true** in gradle.properties.for more details please refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, thanks, I solved it by doing migration first on a refresh copy without doing anything to gradle versions.